# How to convert a Set<Class<?>> to a List?

Tags: java, list, set

I am calling a method N times:

```
 Set<Class<?>> userManagementEntities = new Reflections("com.domain.api.userManagement.domain").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
```

It return a `Set<Class<?>>`.

I have a setter `exposeIdsFor(Class<?>... domainTypes)`

How can I convert my `Set<Class<?>>` so the function `exposeIdsFor` doesn't throw compilation error?

Comment: You are creating a list of lists of classes there.

Comment: i am confused. where is your `Set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `exposeIdsFor(Class<?>... domainTypes)` expects an array of `Class` objects. You can convert your `Set<Class<?>>` to an array with its `toArray` method.

```
exposeIdsFor(userManagementEntities.toArray(new Class[userManagementEntities.size()]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a list of lists of classes there.

And you wouldn't need to copy an ArrayList into an ArrayList either, you're simply copying a list; not to mention it has to be an [array](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#exposeIdsFor-java.lang.Class...-).

Just put the things into the `ArrayList` with `addAll`.

```
List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(new Reflections("com.domain.api.userManagement.domain").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class));
// ...

Class<?>[] array = list.toArray(new Class<?>[0]);
config.exposeIdsFor(array);
```

Comment: @BigDong presumably you had this problem previously? Updated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect each `Set<Class<?>>` to contain exactly one object. If this is the case, add a helper method to pick the item from the set, like this:

```
static Class<?> getAnnotatedClass(String name, Class<?> annotated) {
    Set<Class<?>> res = new Reflections(name).getTypesAnnotatedWith(annotated);
    if (res.size() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Missing "+name);
    }
    return res.iterator().next();
}
```